# System.Net.WebException: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Tags: c#, парсер

Пытаюсь получить все данные из https://api.dmarket.com/exchange/v1/offers-by-title?Title=%E2%98%85%20Sport%20Gloves%20%7C%20Vice%20%28Field-Tested%29&Limit=100
Но выдает ошибку: System.Net.WebException: "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.". Хотя я авторизовался на сайте.

Вот код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string price = "";          
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                price = wc.DownloadString("https://api.dmarket.com/exchange/v1/offers-by- 
title?Title=%E2%98%85%20Sport%20Gloves%20%7C%20Vice%20%28Field-Tested%29&Limit=100");
            Console.WriteLine(price);
        }
    }


}
```

Пытался вставить:

```
myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Но ничего не помогает.

Comment: Вы не авторизовались на сайте. И WebClient устарел, используйте асинхронный HttpClient. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14628278/12888024 - как-то так оно делается для HttpClient.

Comment: 1. авторизовались в браузере не равно авторизовались в коде. 2. чтобы авторизоваться в запросе вы должны указать специальный хеадер с токеном авторизации (если это предусмотренно на сайте) или установить куки, взятые из браузера после авторизовации

Comment: поизучайте [это](https://docs.dmarket.com/v1/swagger.html?_gl=1*dsgl39*_ga*MTA1NTk2ODYyMy4xNjI4MTk0MDIx*_ga_J73817TZWR*MTYyODE5NDAyMS4xLjEuMTYyODE5NDA4My42MA..), а именно "Действительный HTTP-запрос к торговому API должен включать 3 заголовка запроса:..."